# Creation of new database connection in java using oracle jdbc template

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

```
/* connection pool created with 5 connections based on the region specific.
 with below code it will get connection from connection pool which is already created.*/

Connection con = DatasourceClient.getDataSourceMap.get(region).getConnection();
OracleConnection oConn = con.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
```

Will above code will get two connections from pool and do i need to close both con and Oconn ?

i am getting pool exhausted and connection closed exceptions tried many ways by changing pool properties.
So just want to know what above code is doing.

tried closing the above connections but didn't get any difference results.

Using Oracle Jdbc template instead of spring jdbc because in my procedures there are array values which in few cases only input, in some cases only output and other both INOUT.

Can any one help me in this please ? Thank you.

Comment: As you are manually handling `Connection` object you also need to close them. You should be fine by closing the outer connection as that will initially delegate to the `OracleConnection` and the net result should be it should be returned to the pool. I would however suggest making this transparent and use something like the `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to automatically select the `DataSource` you need and let Spring handle all the dificulties of opening/closing connections (and yes you can still `unwrap` with a Spring managed connection).

Answer (score 0):

No, it will get only a single connection out, which you then unwrap to it's actual class.

However you will need to call `con.close()` (and never `oCon.close()`) to return the connection back to the pool. This is because the wrapper's `close()` doesn't actually close the connection, it returns it back to the pool.

Comment: thank you Kayaman, right now doing the same but connection is not going back to tomcat connection pool and i edited my question too why i am using oracle jdbc template instead of Spring Jdbc. If you have any info on that could you please help me